# cakephp empty pages for some of the controllers

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I have a stange problem with my CakePHP (ver 2.5) app.

I developed it on xampp, and everything was fine. Now I moved it to live server and the problem is - some of the controllers work just fine, but others render no content whatsoever (no layout, or error page either). The app seems to know that these controllers exist, because it outputs empty pages when I try to visit their actions, and errors, when i purposely misspell controller name.

What may be the cause of this situation?

Comment: Have you checked the server's PHP error logs?

Comment: and/or your Cake app error logs ? (in `app/tmp/logs/error.log`)

Comment: Cake error log is empty, and unfortunately I have no PHP error log available, and not a way to make it happen... any other ideas to figure out the problem?

Comment: I was able to get php error log. Sort of. The problem is - my php.ini config has error_log set to null. I have no way to change it permanently, but I was able to change it on the fly in bootstrap.php, by adding `ini_set("error_log","SOME_FILE")` - when I execute `error_log("whatever");` it does go to `SOME_FILE`, which makes me think it should work. But, when I execute my script which does not work it produces no log to error log file. Further ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  Acl controlled Application, maybe you didn't upload the aros, acos, and aros_acos table. In case you did, try this on the cakephp console "cake AclExtras.AclExtras aco_sync" and re upload db  ! .

Let me know if this works for you .

Comment: In this case, the app would give an authorization error message, not a blank page.